# Svg files in root directory dist/root

Tags: angular-cli

after running "ng build" there are many .svg files in the main directory of the output in the dist folder.

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AbUO.png)

May be it's from node_modules/material-icon
can i somehow specify it that assets like this will not be placed in the root?